# How to use two ng-repeats in one table row?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am struggling with some refactoring of a grid to a table. In the current grid I will have two ng-repeats to load the correct data from a controller. 
See below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"> <b>{{ 'title' | translate}}</b></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><b>{{ 'date' | translate}}</b></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><b>{{ 'time' | translate}}</b></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><b>{{ 'EventState' | translate}}</b></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
<div class="row editEventTabs" ng-repeat="event in profileCtrl.user._events">
    <div ng-repeat="date in profileCtrl.eventDates(event, profileCtrl.user) ">
        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="/#/eventProfile/{{event._id}}/{{date}}">{{event.title}}</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">{{ date }}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><i>{{ event.start | date:'HH:mm' }} - {{ event.end | date:'HH:mm' }}</i></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">{{ event.eventStatus | translate }}</div>
        <button class="col-xs-2 btn btn-default" ng-click="profileCtrl.unsubscribe(event, date)">{{ 'unSubscribe' | translate }}</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first ng-repeat will load the events, and some of the events are recurring, so I want to show all the events from a recurring event below each other. The second ng-repeat will load the date which belong to a specific event.

Now i want to refactor this in a table, but I can't figure out how to get the data from the two ng-repeats in one table row..

I need a table because of some data I want to sort / filter, which is currently not possible in a grid. (If I am right)

**UPDATE**

First, thanks all for the answer already. 
The output must be something like this: 
[Lay out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feN0I.jpg)

So, the link of the event and the date are retrieved from the controllers.

**UPDATE 2**

It is working now. With this code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th> {{ 'title' | translate}} </th>
        <th> {{ 'date' | translate}} </th>
        <th> {{ 'startTime' | translate}} </th>
        <th>{{ 'endTime' | translate }}</th>
        <th> {{ 'state' | translate}} </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tbody ng-repeat="event in profileCtrl.user._events  ">
        <tr ng-repeat="date in profileCtrl.eventDates(event, profileCtrl.user) | orderBy: date " >
            <td><a href="/#/eventProfile/{{event._id}}/{{date}}">{{event.title}}</a></td>
            <td> {{date }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ event.start | date:'HH:mm' }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ event.end | date:'HH:mm' }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ event.eventStatus | translate }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="profileCtrl.unsubscribe(event, date)">{{ 'unSubscribe' | translate }}</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense 1st `ng-repeat` to be rows, and the second one columns (cells)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your event object structure, you should have an array of dates inside each object in *profileCtrl.user._events* :

```
{
    _id: 'your event id'
    title: 'Sample title',
    start: [Date Object],
    end: [Date Object],
    eventStatus: 'your event status',
    dates: [
        [Date Object],
        [Date Object],
        [Date Object]
    ]
}
```

**template**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ 'title' | translate}}</th>
                    <th>{{ 'date' | translate}}</th>
                    <th>{{ 'time' | translate}}</th>
                    <th>{{ 'EventState' | translate}}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <!-- Iterating events -->
                <tr ng-repeat="event in profileCtrl.user._events"> 
                    <td>
                        {{event.title}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- Iterating event.dates -->
                        <ul ng-repeat="date in event.dates">
                            <li>
                                {{date}} - 
                                <a href ng-click="profileCtrl.unsubscribe(event, date)">{{ 'unSubscribe' | translate }}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ event.start | date:'HH:mm' }} - {{ event.end | date:'HH:mm' }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ event.eventStatus | translate }}
                    </td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi amit, thanks! Your setup is indeed very logic. Unfortunately, I didn't start at this project and the logic of saving an event is different then yours. This can't change at the moment.. 
The 'profileCtrl.user._events' is a reference to my Mongochef database.

Comment: You need to maniuplate data in the service (or controller) after getting it from the database in order to have the best structure for your template

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect with "profileCtrl.eventDates(event, profileCtrl.user)" re array with one value?

Comment: Excuse me :Do you expect with "profileCtrl.eventDates(event, profileCtrl.user)" retrive just an array with one value?

Comment: The "profileCtrl.eventDates(event, profileCtrl.user)"  will get the date which for the specific event. See picture in updated message please.

Answer (score 1):

If you just retrieve an array with one value, you don't need a nested ng-repeat.
You could use retrieve the date you need with ng-init.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th> {{ 'title' | translate}} </th>
        <th> {{ 'date' | translate}} </th>
        <th> {{ 'startTime' | translate}} </th>
        <th>{{ 'endTime' | translate }}</th>
        <th> {{ 'state' | translate}} </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="event in profileCtrl.user._events" ng-init="date = profileCtrl.eventDates(event, profileCtrl.user)[0]">
            <td><a href="/#/eventProfile/{{event._id}}/{{date}}">{{event.title}}</a></td>
            <td> {{date }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ event.start | date:'HH:mm' }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ event.end | date:'HH:mm' }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ event.eventStatus | translate }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="profileCtrl.unsubscribe(event, date)">{{ 'unSubscribe' | translate }}</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use angular.merge({}, obj1, obj2);

It works fine for me : http://codepen.io/hmache/pen/qNXZNZ

```
scope.obj1 = [{
    id: 1,
    city: 'NYS'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    city: 'haway'
  }];

  $scope.obj2 = [{
    race: 'Human',
    name: 'Alex'
  }, {
    race: 'Alien',
    name: 'Ho'
  }];

  $scope.data = angular.merge({}, $scope.obj1, $scope.obj2);
```

source :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge